# Extension method on multiple generics

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I've found the below "Convert to Datatable" code which I've altered to be an extension method for the IList interface. Rather than copy and paste the code again in my library I want to also make the below work for ICollection. I can copy and paste the code and change the IList at the top, then then I would have two copies of the same script.

```
public static DataTable ConvertToDatatable<T>(this IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }
    object[] values = new object[props.Count];
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

I've even tried changing the first line to something like

```
public static DataTable ConvertToDatatable<T>(this N<T> data) where N : IList<T>, ICollection<T>
```

but having no luck. Is it possible to make the extension to work on the multiple collection types?

Comment: Why not simply using `IEnumerable<T>`, you use it only  in foreach and would work for both `IList` and `ICollection`

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. I'm still fairly new to the lists/collections side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an `IList<T>` is an `ICollection<T>` it should be sufficient to just define the extension method on the `ICollection<T>` type. It should automatically be available to a variable of type `IList<T>`.

Comment: Thanks, it's all confusing what interface is another interface etc, I've just tested this and it works as want it to. I'm guessing using IEnumerable  is better though.

Comment: True, `IEnumerable<T>` is even better is you only iterate through the data.